# Letter of recommendations from instructors at a coaching institute

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

Currently I'm doing an automation course in a [coaching institute](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/775/is-coaching-classtutoring-on-topic).

We need to submit three letters of recommendations for a masters programme. I have one from my previous college, and another one from my previous employer, but I still need a third one.

Is it acceptable to submit a letter of recommendation from the coaching institute where I'm studying, instead of from a regular college or university?

Comment: It would help if the OP (or someone else who knows) would specify what a "coaching institute" is, for those of us who haven't heard of it, and preferably also provide a country tag if that would help to explain the situation of how it is different than a typical higher-education institution. It could also be helpful to specify to what country you are applying to graduate schools, as cultures can vary on how they run graduate admissions.

Comment: @BrianDHall In my meta question [Is Coaching Class(Tutoring) on-topic?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/775/546), I explained what coaching class is in my location. Although I don't know where the OP of this question is from (I am guessing he/she is from India), I think the coaching institute is similar to coaching class in my question. Hope that meta question will help a little. Thanks for your understanding. (not every westerner would even try to figure it out what it is).

Comment: @scaaahu Thanks for that clarification, it's an interesting concept. I suppose the US equivalent would be something like a test-prep program, like Kaplan or The Princeton Review? It sounds a bit like the more intensive version of options test-prep companies can offer here, like a 1-2 week in-person course, so the US may have no direct equivalent. Are the coaching institute programs generally longer or more in-depth than that?

Comment: @BrianDHall In my location, it's generally longer than a few months (depending on the purposes you go to them). Prep school for GRE/TOEFL is about 2 or 3 months. For others, I heard people take whatever long it takes before passing the entrance exam because their purpose is to ensure  they will pass the entrance exam. Some of the entrance exam problems are very hard, it takes quite a bit time to learn how to solve them while taking the exams.

Comment: From OP's name, it seems like s/he's from India where "coaching classes" are like small schools with the sole purpose of making one clear university entrance exams. Unlike the USA where admission to universities depends on various things like recommendation letters, SOP, academic record, etc...In India, a single exam is what decides where you're gonna go for further study. In some cases , followed by an interview.  scaaahu 's explanation of coaching classes in his country fits the description of Indian coachings too.

Comment: Except that tutors rarely have PhDs here. To OP, if your letter writers at your coaching know you well, have published research done on their name(because I think this thing matters a lot) then I don't see why you should not get recommendations from them.